# How to make an animation look consistent and smooth

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

`So I have a total of 6 images that when animated, creates the illusion of a person walking. The problem is its not smooth, refresh(), invalidate(),update() have failed me. How do I go about this.

```
namespace Runner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
        Keys moveRight;
        Keys moveLeft;
    public static bool isMovingR = false;
    public static bool isMovingL = false;

    Bitmap stnd = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Standing);
    static Bitmap wlk_1_RL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_1_RL);
    static Bitmap wlk_2_RL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_2_RL);
    static Bitmap wlk_3_RL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_3_RL);
    static Bitmap wlk_4_LL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_4_LL);
    static Bitmap wlk_5_LL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_5__LL);
    static Bitmap wlk_6_LL = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Walk_6_LL);

    Graphics gfx;
    Animation animate = new Animation(new Bitmap[] { wlk_1_RL, wlk_2_RL, wlk_3_RL,
        wlk_4_LL, wlk_5_LL, wlk_6_LL });


    Timer timer = new Timer();

    int imageX = 5;
    int imageY = 234;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        moveRight = Keys.D;
        moveLeft = Keys.A;

        if (Keys.D == moveRight)
        {
            isMovingR = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Interval = 50;
            timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;                
            //imageX += 5;
            Refresh();
        } else if (Keys.A == moveLeft)
        {
            isMovingL = true;
            imageX -= 5;
            Refresh();
        }

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gfx = this.CreateGraphics();
        gfx.DrawImage(animate.Frame2Draw(), imageX, imageY);
        //Refresh(); Invalidate(); Update();
    }
}
```

}

Now, the problem is being able to make the animation consistent and smooth

UPDATE...animation class

```
 public class Animation
{
    int slctdImg = 0;
    public static Bitmap[] images;
    Bitmap frame2Draw;

    public Animation(Bitmap[] frames)
    {
        foreach (Bitmap btm in frames)
        {
            btm.MakeTransparent();
        }
        images = frames;
    }

    public Bitmap Frame2Draw()
    {

        if (slctdImg < images.Length)
        {
            frame2Draw = images[slctdImg];
            slctdImg++;
        }
        if (slctdImg >= images.Length)
        {
            slctdImg = 0;
            frame2Draw = images[slctdImg];
        }
        return frame2Draw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: So there are still frames missing? (Always a bit hard to tell..). You should update the question to show the current version of the code. (You did correct the errors I have pointed you to?)

Comment: not yet, your solutions were quite helpful, I moved the drawing to a timer.tick event than the load or paint event  because of "event handler" problems with "timer.tick  and I made my images static, thus being able to make scope was public, so no instantiation required. anyways the animation works-ish, the problem is it leave this trail. For ex, when the animation starts, frame 1 will be drawn, but the thing is the frame isn't  deleted,  Looks like this. https://www.flickr.com/gp/154644657@N06/h685aC, this issue is caused when using update().if I use invalidate or Refresh, image becomes buggy.

Comment: Omg, I'm sorry, I feel like I'm confusing you... ok, uhm I deleted the first comment so don't worry about it. The current problem depicts my current status. Thanks

Comment: Two questions: 1) you have a `timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;` in a key event. do you ever delete those handlers?? You really should do that, or, better, only create the hook exactly one time or else they will all run each time, which results in gaps. -  2) What is animate.Frame2Draw()?

Comment: animate.Frame2Draw() is a method in other file that I created that loops the frames(images) and returns them I will post the code above

Comment: I thought so. What about the multiple event handler hooking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143582/discussion-between-jamisco-and-taw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many issues:

- I wonder why you would call [MakeTransparent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzst10b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on each `Tick`?? I doubt it does what you expect.. It is changing pixels and rather expensive; you ought to cache the images instead.
- Nor why you create an array of bitmap on each `Tick`???  And **since it is always created the same way it always displays only the 1st image**.. This should answer your question.

Further issues:

- Using `this.CreateGraphics();` will fail to create a **persistent** result although that may not be your aim as you try to animate.
- Remember that a `Timer.Interval` can't run faster than `15-30 ms`; also that winforms is notoriously **bad** at animation.
- Remember that c# is zero-based, so this `slctdImg > images.Length` should probably be `slctdImg >= images.Length`

Here is what you should do instead:

- Move the instantiation either to the form load or maybe to a key event.
- Move the drawing to the `Paint` event of the form.
- In the `Tick` count up frames and/or position and trigger the `Paint` by calling `Invalidate` on the form!

**Update:**

One more issue is the way you hook up the `Tick` event each time the right key is pressed. **Hooking up** an event **multiple times** will result in it **running multiple times**; this will create to gaps/jumps in your animation..

**Either** add an **unhook** each time before hooking up (it will fail quietly the 1st time)

```
timer.Tick -= timer1_Tick;
timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;
```

**or** (better) hook it up only **once** in the original set up!